# How to call class from another module in SpringBoot, Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a Spring Boot multi-module gradle project, and I am trying to call class from another module. I have a `HttpDataClient.java` class that I would like to call in `DataResolver.java` class in another module.

**HttpDataClient.java**

```
public class HttpDataClient implements DataClient{

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpDataClient.class);

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public HttpDataClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public DataResponse getData(String dataId) {
        try{
            JsonNode node = restTemplate.exchange(
                    String.format("/data/%s", dataId),
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    new HttpEntity<>(buildRequest(dataId), headers()),
                    JsonNode.class
            ).getBody();
            return dataResponse(node);
        }catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            String msg = String.format(
                    "Error getting data for dataId: %s",
                    dataId,
                    e.getStatusCode(),
                    e.getResponseBodyAsString());
            LOGGER.error(msg);
            return dataResponse.failed();
        }
    }

    private MultiValueMap<String, String> headers() {
        final LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> mv = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        mv.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        return mv;
    }

    private DataResponse dataResponse(JsonNode node) {
        return DataResponse.dataResponse(
                asString(node, "dataId"),
                asString(node, "dataAuthor"),
                asString(node, "dataAuthorId")
        );
    }

    private JsonNode buildRequest(String dataId) {
        ObjectNode root = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        root.put("dataId", dataId);
        return root;
    }
}
```

So, this class should return some response data from `Data service`. After I would like to get that response data and do something in class in other module.

I am trying to do it like this:

**DataResolver.java**

```
public class DataResolver {

    private final HttpDataClient client;

    public DataResolver(HttpDataClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
}
```

But my `HttpGameDataClient` class that I am trying to use it is not recognized by `DataResolver.java` class.

What am I missing here?
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure the module you need is put as a dependency to the module who need it.

Comment: So I should put it in `build.gradle` file from module that will call the class? I did that I added it as `implementation project(':data-module') and i am getting this error: `projetc with path':data-module'` could not be found in project `'data'`

Comment: I don't really know gradle, I work with Maven instead. You can follow this example for multimodel gradle project https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-gradle-multi-module/

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was missing a dependency to the module who need it or the one who will call the needed class. Added correct dependency like this `api project(":integration:data-module")`, and now I can see the class.

Answer (score 0):

please check if you have added HttpDataClient.class to your spring configuration class. that you are initializing bean.also, check you added the correct dependency

Comment: What do you mean?